# Time complexity of list of list vs set of tuples

Tags: python, list, set, big-o, hashtable

I've always read that set operations are O(1) and at worst O(N) while checking list membership is O(N). So when a friend was checking if a list was in a list before appending the list, I proposed using a set of tuples instead. However, upon timing them, the list of lists were faster! Why is this? How is adding a tuple to a set slower than iterating over the list of lists?

Here's some sample test code

```
import time
a = []
b = []

for i in range(10000):
    a.append(list(range(100)))
    b.append(tuple(range(100)))
    


p=[]
tic=time.perf_counter()
for i in range(100):
    if a[i] not in p:
        p.append(a[i])
toc=time.perf_counter()
print(toc-tic)  # Was about 100ms

q=set()
tic=time.perf_counter()
for i in range(100):
    q.add(b[i])
toc=time.perf_counter()
print(toc-tic)  # Was about 169ms

r=dict()
tic=time.perf_counter()
for i in range(100):
    r[b[i]]=None
toc=time.perf_counter()
print(toc-tic)  # Was about 143ms
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing a good test to see which one is faster because you are adding just a element in `p,q,r` because `a` is composed to just one element repeated : list(range(100)), and the same is true for `b`.

A better test is this modified version where you'll see what you expect, because here you are adding different elements to `a` and `b` :

```
import time
a = []
b = []

for i in range(100000):
    a.append(i)
    b.append(i)
           
p=[]
tic=time.perf_counter()
for i in range(100):
    if a[i] not in p:
        p.append(a[i])
toc=time.perf_counter()
print(toc-tic)  

q=set()
tic=time.perf_counter()
for i in range(100):
    q.add(b[i])
toc=time.perf_counter()
print(toc-tic)  

r=dict()
tic=time.perf_counter()
for i in range(100):
    r[b[i]]=None
toc=time.perf_counter()
print(toc-tic)
```

Comment: Thanks. Although the question was specifically regarding tuples vs lists, not just integer values. However, I was able to modify the list creation to be `list(range(i,m+i))` such that each list is unique, and indeed the timing of the set/dictionary is better than the list search.

Comment: yes but in the end it's not important to have lists or integers, the importance is having unique elements

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nevermind. Turns out it was due to the way the lists were being constructed: the nested lists weren't unique so checking if the list was in the list was essentially O(1) since it was always the first list. Making this slight modification made everything right in the world again:

```
a = []
b=[]
m=100
n=100
for i in range(n):
    a.append(list(range(i,i+m)))
    b.append(tuple(range(i,i+m)))
    


p=[]
tic=time.perf_counter()
for i in range(n):
    if a[i] not in p:
        p.append(a[i])
toc=time.perf_counter()
print(toc-tic)

q=set()
tic=time.perf_counter()
for i in range(n):
    q.add(b[i])
toc=time.perf_counter()
print(toc-tic) 

r=dict()
tic=time.perf_counter()
for i in range(n):
    r[b[i]]=None
toc=time.perf_counter()
print(toc-tic)
```